# .Net Nuget Package install rerturns ssl error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget-package

I am trying to use `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization` namespace in my `C#` project. While I was searching on Google, I found out "dotnet package Newtonsoft.Json" is a way to install the package on ubuntu linux, but it returned below error:

```
writing /tmp/tmpC1RGW5.tmp
error:   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
error:   The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

.Net version is 3.1. 
Please help this C# newbie. Thanks.

Comment: It may be something different, but in 3.1 you should be installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`. In fact, if you are C# newbie, then it may be enough to use the built-in functionality of `System.Text.Json` See docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#net-core-30-api-changes

Comment: That's assuming ASP.NET Core. This question is only tagged with .NET Core.

Comment: Thank you. A reason why I try to use Newtonsoft.Json is I need to send Json query to a websocket server. Is there any way to generate Json query in System.Text.Json namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with your machine certificates.

Check the [github issue here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9571)

> In my /etc/ssl/certs I notice some link to snakeoil certificate in red. so it seem these certificates are missing in my computer.
>
> I recreate them and everything work again.

There are also links in more issues, some fixed and some others related to misconfiguration of ssl:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29942
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30385
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30388

This is not a net core issue nor a nuget issues it seems. It looks a lot more like a connectivity from your workstation issue, more than anything else.